# Is it right a LINQ query to check whether atleast one entity exists in string collection with a matching criteria (rownum<=1)

Tags: linq

I was trying to do something similar to ForEach in LINQ, to find in a string collection whether atleast a single entity is matching with the matching string.

I was trying to create a query something similar to Rownum<=1 in Oracle.

Please suggest if LINQ code is a good approach.

ForEach:

```
bool check(string matchcriteria)
{
  foreach ( string key in Keys)
                if ( key.ToLower() == matchcriteria.ToLower()) return true;
  return false;
}
```

LINQ;

```
bool check(string matchcriteria)
{
 return (from  key in Keys
                           where  key.ToLower() == matchcriteria.ToLower() select 10).FirstOrDefault()==10;
}
```

thanks
Srinivas Pv

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The LINQ [Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx) method would be better suited.

```
bool check(string matchcriteria)
{
    return Keys.Any(key => key.ToLower() == matchcriteria.ToLower());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response....I was just curious about the approach i followed...is there any perfromance issue with my approach?

Comment: It's going to be slower, but probably not by much. Is there reason to believe that this line will be a bottleneck? If so, you'll probably be faster rolling your own loop... if not, Any is definitely less confusing to your readers!

Comment: yes I agree with you ANY best suits in this scenario....ofcorse this will not be a bottleneck :)..Thank you for the help